# How to import typings from self-written module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a hard time figuring out how to solve the following issue because I don't know what to search for. Let me explain: I've written a class using TypeScript that I'm exporting:

```
class MyAPIClass {
  myMethod(one:number) : void;
  secondMethod(text:string) : number;
}
export = MyAPIClass;
```

Now I'm using that class in another TypeScript project of mine:

```
import MyAPIClass = require('../path/MyAPIClass');

let myClass = new MyAPIClass();
myClass.myMethod(1);
```

This is working fine, but I don't get the "typings". My editor doesn't recognize the types from the other file. I also can't do this:

```
let myClass : MyAPIClass = new MyAPIClass();
```

How can I "import" the typings too?

Comment: you should use import instead of require (I mean the keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead

```
export class MyAPIClass {
  myMethod(one:number) : void;
  secondMethod(text:string) : number;
}
```

This exports the class as a named export. Then in your other file you can do

```
import {MyAPIClass} from '../path/MyAPIClass'
```

to bring it into your projects. From there

```
let myClass : MyAPIClass = new MyAPIClass();
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :)